# Semicolon after foreach statement has "interesting" result. Why?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Just had an *AHA!* moment with adding a `;` after a `foreach` loop by accident. Funnily this didn't throw an error, but skipped(?) everything in the loops array and just touches the last element.

Test code:

```
$test_array = array(
    'a' => 'one',
    'b' => 'two',
    'c' => 'three'
);
foreach ( $test_array as $key => $val );
    echo $val;
```

Question: Why does this happen?

Comment: the semi-colon is terminating the function.  It looks like you're just saying `foreach` stop `echo $val`

Comment: I believe you're saying "loop through all of the values but don't do anything, then echo out the last $val item".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A semicolon ends the statement and a foreach statement is similar to a function - it opens up a scope. If you do not open up a multi-line scope with curly brackets, the scope runs to the next semicolon so

```
foreach ( $test_array as $key => $val );
```

is the equivalent of

```
foreach ( $test_array as $key => $val ) { }
```

Which I believe answers your question as to why it behaves this way.

Answer (score 4):

When you do:

```
foreach ( $test_array as $key => $val );
```

Here all the foreach is executed (passing by each element) but as you putted a `;` there is no other instruction taken advantage of that, instead when it ends all the iteration, `$val` contains the value of the last element, which you happen to echo in your next instruction:

```
echo $val;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `;` ends the loop, so that would be equivalent to

```
foreach ( $test_array as $key => $val ){ /* do nothing */ }
```

at the end of the loop $val has the value of the last key, therefore it echoes it

Answer (score 1):

That's standard "feature" of all languages with C-like syntax. Namely,

```
for (...);
```

means

```
for (...) { }
```

Also, in your case, after `foreach` loop ends, `$val` doesn't disappear, but still exists and holds the last value it was assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

The loop runs, performing the iterating and condition checking, but nothing else.  Then the `echo` command executes, and at this point `$val` contains the last value it was assigned.  And the last value it was assigned was the the last value from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

All you are doing is looping to all but doing nothing beside the last element.